# jQuery .css('margin-left') gives "auto" back in IE7 and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the margin-left value of an element. This works fine in Chrome, FireFox & IE9 but in IE7 and IE8 I get "auto" back:

```
alert($('#'+page+'menubuttoncontainer').css('margin-left').replace('px', ''));
```

How can I get a number back instead of "auto"?

Comment: It might help if we knew why you needed the margin-left...

Comment: I'm using this version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js

Answer (score 6):

`.css` return the value of the CSS.

In order to get the position, you should use the offsets functions: http://api.jquery.com/offset/

Or the position function: http://api.jquery.com/position/

Comment: Can you explain further? I don't see how I can get the margin-left with this.

Comment: You won't get margin-left as this value virtually don't exist (you setup `auto` in your style sheet). You'll get a top/left object in return, and with this you could deduce the position of your box. Although, like someone told earlier (but seem to have remove his comments), you can also check `.position()` if this make more sense in your use case. Position will return position relative to the parent bloc.